# How to store the filenames of different shapes and color obtained through Matlab GUIDE at a location

Tags: python, matlab, matlab-guide

I am using Matlab Guide to create a GUI which takes shapes and color from 2 different folders containing different Shapes and colors.I have developed a python script to fill a particular color inside a particular shape.In order to get the user input about the choice of his/her shape and filling color I need to return the filenames and use those filenames in my python script.

My python script is working fine.Iam facing trouble to store filenames obtained from the matlab to be stored at a location.

```
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to popupmenu1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hints: contents = cellstr(get(hObject,'String')) returns popupmenu1 
contents as cell array
%     contents{get(hObject,'Value')} returns selected item frompopupmenu1
items = get(hObject,'String');
global item_selected
index_selected = get(hObject,'Value');
item_selected = items{index_selected};
display (item_selected)
matfrompy;
```

Below is the code of matfrompy.m

```
global filename1;
global filename2;
global item_selected

switch item_selected
    case 'Shapes'
        [file,path] = 
uigetfile('H:\baibhav\MPEG7dataset\changed_name\*.jpg'); 
    if isequal(file,0)  %if users clicks on cancel button it returns 0
     disp('User selected Cancel')
    else
        [~, file1, ~] = fileparts(file);   

        disp(file1);
        filename1 = str2num(file1);
        disp(filename1);
    end

case 'Colour'
    [file,path] = uigetfile('H:\Color Files\*.png'); 
    if isequal(file,0)  %if users clicks on cancel button it returns 0
     disp('User selected Cancel')
    else
        [~, file2, ~] = fileparts(file);    %In the syntax of fileparts, filepath and extension are taken to be ~
        disp(file2);
        filename2 = str2num(file2);
        disp(filename2);
    end
end

fid = fopen('write_credentials.txt', 'at');

if fid ~= -1
    %fprintf(fid, '%s', email_id);   % %s and %c are format specifier
    fprintf(fid, '%c', ' '); fprintf(fid, '%d', filename1);
    fprintf(fid, '%c', ' '); fprintf(fid, '%d', filename2);
    fprintf(fid, '\n'); %this is working..
    fclose(fid);
else
    warningMessage = sprintf('Cannot open file %s', filename);
    uiwait(warndlg(warningMessage));
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify the "trouble"? What part of the code doesn't work?

Comment: As you can see, I am storing the filenames into a text file named write_credentials.txt  But the filenames are not getting appended there and thus I am not able to use them for my other code.